# Error in metadata reply for topic test (PartCnt 0): Broker: Unknown topic or partition' } using node-rdkafka

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

Hi am getting this error when am trying to connect to kafka remotely on my prod server.My messages are not getting produced and/or consumed from my code.Let me know if any code sample is needed.Just want to know what can be the reasons for receiving this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case some one else go through the same issue: the issue for me was i was using it with kerberos the principal name and the keytab file that I was using didn't have permissions to create topic or produce/consume message!